# Correct implementation of IEqualityComparer for List<Dictionary<string,string>>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have two `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` that represents two tables. I want to get Dictionary objects that are different in those tables.

I'm trying to use Except method because it is basically do what I want: it returns the difference. But because this method uses default comparer I have created my own IEqualityComparer implementation.

On the example below it works pretty good, but in real life Dictionaries are much more complex, so I wonder - is my implementation is a good solution or it must be enhanced?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var table1 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>{
        new Dictionary<string,string>{
        {"md5","0x1234"},
        {"file_name","name1234"},
        {"size","1234"}},

        new Dictionary<string,string>{
        {"md5","0x1234"},
        {"file_name","name1234"},
        {"size","1234"}},
        };

        var table2 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>{
        new Dictionary<string,string>{
        {"md5","0x1234"},
        {"file_name","name1234"},
        {"size","1234"}},

        new Dictionary<string,string>{
        {"md5","0x5678"},
        {"file_name","name5678"},
        {"size","5678"}}
        };

        var diff = table2.Except(table1, new DictionaryComparer());

        foreach (var item in diff)
        {
            foreach (var value in item)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class DictionaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, string> first, Dictionary<string, string> second)
        {
            if (first == second) return true;
            if ((first == null) || (second == null)) return false;
            if (first.Count != second.Count) return false;

            foreach (var k in first.Keys)
                if (!second.ContainsKey(k))
                    return false;

            foreach (var k in first.Keys)
                if (!first[k].Equals(second[k]))
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, string> obj)
        {
            int resultValue = 0;

            if (obj == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }        

            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                resultValue += (item.Key.Length + item.Value.Length);
            }

            return resultValue;
        }

    }
```

Comment: That isn't the best implementation of a hash code, you should google `GetHashCode implementation` and read the stackoverflow posts

Comment: Well, sounds like you could go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CallumLinington Maybe it is not so important if its dictionary is not going to be stored in a hasset or dictionary?

Comment: Hm, it seems that if there will be objects will different KVP but items in these KVP will have the same length I'll get same hash for such objects, which is not really nice, after googling a bit more i've tried

                foreach (var item in obj)
                {
                    hash += (17 * item.Key.GetHashCode()) + item.Value.GetHashCode();
                }

Answer (score -1):

I think a bit cleaner solution would be following :

```
public class DictionaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, string> x, KeyValuePair<string, string> y)
    {
        return x.Key.Equals(y.Key) 
            && x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, string> obj)
    {
        return string.Concat(obj.Key, obj.Value)
            .GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a string inside the `GetHashCode()` is a relatively expensive operation for a function that should be very lean and return very quickly.

Comment: Hm , and how do we compare values in dictionary?

Comment: @sstan the implementation of hash generation I think is out of this Q&A scope, therefore the code is just a naive example.

Comment: You have access to KeyValue pairs, so the object gives you access to both. I updated an answer code.